# How can i use variable in array for loop based hash tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

node.js file

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
pool.getConnection(function (err, con) {
    con.query('select roll1 from webchart.data', function (err, result) {
        if (err) console.error(err);            
        res.render('index', { title: 'Roll', year: new Date().getFullYear(), parms: result});
    });
});
```

.jade file

```
       script(type='text/javascript').
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        var a = 1;
        function drawChart() {                         
        var dataR1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dataR1.addColumn('number', 'time');
        dataR1.addColumn('number', 'roll1');                                   
        dataR1.addRow([1, #{parms[a].roll1}]);
        dataR1.addRow([2, #{parms[2].roll1}]);
```

500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'roll1' of undefined

how can i?